# Keep specific rows among two duplicates

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a files with multiple duplicated pairs. I want to keep one of the duplicates based on a value in another column. In my example I want to keep the duplicate that has "Present" in the column "Detected".

```
structure(list(variable = c("CPCT02030264T", "DRUP01090004T", 
"DRUP01160001T", "DRUP01090004T", "DRUP01160001T"), value = c(0, 
0, 0, 22.2109790032886, 23.0078421452062), Detected = c("Absent", 
"Absent", "Absent", "Present", "Present"), Method = c("DNA", 
"DNA", "DNA", "RNA", "RNA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(39529L, 
145909L, 146881L, 304365L, 305283L))

    variable    value Detected Method
39529  CPCT02030264T  0.00000   Absent    DNA
145909 DRUP01090004T  0.00000   Absent    DNA
146881 DRUP01160001T  0.00000   Absent    DNA
304365 DRUP01090004T 22.21098  Present    RNA
305283 DRUP01160001T 23.00784  Present    RNA
```

out

```
            variable    value Detected Method
39529  CPCT02030264T  0.00000   Absent    DNA
304365 DRUP01090004T 22.21098  Present    RNA
305283 DRUP01160001T 23.00784  Present    RNA
```

Comment: `df %>% filter(Detected == "Present")`?

Comment: No, because not all rows are duplicates in the data frames.

Comment: Can you edit your data set to include non-duplicates? and show your expected outcomes? are duplicates only one one column? or do they have the same value on all columns? it's a bit unclear

Comment: Maybe your command combined with an if statement?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `slice_max` by group to keep only the maximum value per group depending on the value of `Detected`. In that sense the maximum of `Detected` is the latest by alphabetical order:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  slice_max(Detected)

# A tibble: 3 × 4
# Groups:   variable [3]
  variable      value Detected Method
  <chr>         <dbl> <chr>    <chr> 
1 CPCT02030264T   0   Absent   DNA   
2 DRUP01090004T  22.2 Present  RNA   
3 DRUP01160001T  23.0 Present  RNA
```

Answer (score 1):

[dplyr::row_number()](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/ranking.html) can rank the rows within each value of `variable`.  If you sort by `Detected` descending, the "Present" values will appear on top of the "Absent".  Then filter on the top row within each group (*i.e.*, `rn` is 1).

```r
ds |> 
  dplyr::group_by(variable) |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    rn = dplyr::row_number(dplyr::desc(Detected)),
  ) |> 
  dplyr::filter(rn == 1L) |> 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

Then I like executing [dplyr::ungroup()](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_by.html) so future operations apply to the entire dataset, instead of treating them as subsets.

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  variable      value Detected Method    rn
  <chr>         <dbl> <chr>    <chr>  <int>
1 CPCT02030264T   0   Absent   DNA        1
2 DRUP01090004T  22.2 Present  RNA        1
3 DRUP01160001T  23.0 Present  RNA        1
```

Comment: I'd recommend to load the package in the beginning of your answer to avoid all those `dplyr::`

Comment: @Maël, I know I'm in the minority and that many R users don't quality a function's package.  But I like how it communicates the intent and how it eliminates the chance of calling the wrong package's function (even if that function hasn't been developed & released yet).  The practice is standard among most other languages.  If someone is running code interactively, it doesn't matter too much; but a lot of my group's code runs with automation (without a human eye checking each execution).